# Simulating a touch screen on mobile device

Tags: windows-mobile, touchscreen

Does anyone know if C++ or C# has a method to simulate a touch screen?  For example I have device that has an interface with six buttons.  Each button represents a program so when a button is touched, it will open a program that's related to that button.  So I want simulate a touch screen to touch each button.  Can it be done?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2005 onwards you can make use of a Mobile Device emulator for creating smartphone and Windows Mobile applications. I have used it for creating various C# applications using the [.NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w6ah6cw1.aspx), which contains a [cut-down feature set of the normal .NET framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/2weec7k5.aspx).

See this link for information on Windows Smartphone development.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t.aspx

Comment: sorry, it's not related to my question also I already know how to create mobile application with C# in VS2005/08.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run your code through a Windows Mobile emulator: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1A7A6B52-F89E-4354-84CE-5D19C204498A&displaylang=en

This program will let you simulate windows mobile v 6.1 on your PC.

Comment: it's not related to my question.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=272678) you have it. And some other helpful link [here](http://bansky.net/blog/2007/08/simulate-keystrokes-in-windows-mobile/comments.html).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links.  I will start from there.